# Google material icons change size with font size property works in inline CSS but the same does not work in external CSS. Why?

Tags: css, web, fonts, icons, size

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="material-icons">amp_stories</i>
</body>
</html>

    /*CSS CODE EXTERNAL*/

    .material-icons{
        font-size: 40px;
     }
```

I used material icons in my website. They do not change size when I use font size property in external CSS. I tried Inline CSS, it works well but not in external CSS. If I inspect element it shows icon's font size 24 PX. and if I delete it then my eternal CSS code works until I refresh the web page.

Comment: How sure are you that external style sheet is referenced correctly and Yes, we need code to validate.

Comment: I can share code with you but how

Comment: Hmmm.. there is a `<>` icon when you add your question so the code goes there.

Comment: i have added code, open it in vs code and name files and link them together. the icon do not change size with external css. kindly guide me

Comment: thank you so much you can't imagine how glad i am by this solution. actually i am making a social media website and the code i provided you was just a demo of problem i was facing it is not actual code of my website. can you give me any of yoursocial media account detail so that we can keep in touch.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prepend `i` into the class.

```css
i.material-icons {
  font-size: 98px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="material-icons">amp_stories</i>
</body>

</html>
```

different Sizes:

```css
i.md10px {
  font-size: 10px;
}

i.md20px {
  font-size: 20px;
}

i.md40px {
  font-size: 40px;
}

i.md60px {
  font-size: 60px;
}

i.md90px {
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="material-icons md10px">amp_stories</i>
  <i class="material-icons md20px">amp_stories</i>
  <i class="material-icons md40px">amp_stories</i>
  <i class="material-icons md60px">amp_stories</i>
  <i class="material-icons md90px">amp_stories</i>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nope, in my first snippet I used same code as OPs I have not added any extra class, the second snippet I just used class to make code minimal fore diff sizes.

Comment: Ok, I swap/changed the order of the stylesheet OP used, and I don't see any difference : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/jLr4g13e/1/

Comment: Huh, this really is odd. Your Fiddle shows a 24px sized icon on my screen... investigating this ....

Comment: I stand corrected, apparently stylesheets work on a first come, first serve basis. Need to check a few externals of my own now...upped you answer for this! (removed incorrect comments too).